# Javascript changing position won't work on Chrome or IE

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, position, css-position

Changing position through javascript works through Firefox but not Chrome or IE.

```
<script language="javascript">
function move (){
  document.cat.style.right=0;
}
</script>
<img src="cat.gif" id="cat" style="position:absolute; right:500; top:500" onClick="move ();">
```

Also, this is my first time asking something on here so if I'm doing something wrong please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

var catStyle = document.getElementById('cat');
    catStyle.style.right=0;

Answer (score 0):

Using `document.<id>` is, as you discovered, only supported in Firefox. It's better to use `document.getElementById('cat')`

Also, try to avoid using the `style` attribute unless absolutely necessary. It's best practice to have all CSS in a `style` tag, or better yet an included stylesheet. Also, you were missing units for your `right` and `left` attributes - always be sure that all numbers have a unit. I'm assuming in this case you meant to use pixels.

This should do what you expect (I changed the URL of the image for illustrative purposes):

```js
function move (){
    document.getElementById('cat').style.right=0;
}
```

```css
#cat {
    position:absolute;
    right:500px;
    top:500px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" id="cat" onClick="move();">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img    
  src="cat.gif" 
  id="cat" 
  style="position:absolute; right:500px; top:500px;" 
  onClick="move ();"
>

<script>

   function move (){
     document.getElementById('cat').style.right="0px";
   }

</script>
```

Using units with your style helps the JavaScript kick in. You can use getElementById or querySelector to grab your DOM Element.

Here is the JSFiddle to give you a space to play around in with the example you provided: https://jsfiddle.net/8a2drg7p/1/